# View pager used to show tutorial is very slow in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to make a small tutorial in my app, with the help of a view pager. The user scrolls from left to right, and the views slide in and out as expected. My only problem is that it is very slow. This is what I did:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);

        findViews();

        init();

        setUserInteraction(); // this works as expected
}

private void init() {
    initViewAnimator();

    slideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
    slideInLeft.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

    slideOutLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    slideOutLeft.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

    slideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
    slideInRight.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

    slideOutRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    slideOutRight.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
}

private void initViewAnimator() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_page_1, viewAnimator, false);
    viewAnimator.addView(view);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_page_2, viewAnimator, false);
    viewAnimator.addView(view);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_page_3, viewAnimator, false);
    viewAnimator.addView(view);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_page_4, viewAnimator, false);
    viewAnimator.addView(view);
}

private void showNext(){
    int displayedChild = viewAnimator.getDisplayedChild();

    if(displayedChild == NUMBER_OF_FRAMES - 1){
        return;
    }
    viewAnimator.setInAnimation(slideInRight);
    viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(slideOutLeft);
    viewAnimator.showNext();
    onAnimationStarted(displayedChild, ++displayedChild);        
}

private void showPrevious(){
    int displayedChild = viewAnimator.getDisplayedChild();
    if(displayedChild == 0){
        return;
    }
    viewAnimator.setInAnimation(slideInLeft);
    viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(slideOutRight);
    viewAnimator.showPrevious();
    onAnimationStarted(displayedChild, --displayedChild);
}
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Each screen has a small text, a small icon, and a background. The backgrounds are roughly 1MB each, with a 749*1311 resolution. Not sure whether the size of the images is the problem. If so, how can I make it so that the image still has quality?
The app has been tested on Nexus 5, Samsung S4, S3 and S2, with the same result every time.

I also tried doing this with a horizontal scroll view, and it was still way too slow.

Comment: A background of 749*1311 resolution isn't as small as you think it is. Try reducing it further (< 512px) will help. I don't know what the backgrounds are but I would suggest you use small repeatable image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a ViewPager, this is trying to reinvent the wheel using custom animations. I'm not sure why the app is laggy, but I strongly recommend you to use the Android native component ViewPager. You can find information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and if you run into troubles, contact me for help.

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that I posted the wrong code. I tried with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter already and it didn't work. But now I built it again from scratch and it works flawlessly.

Comment: I'm glad you got to the bottom if this. Also, I've noticed in your code this method "setUserInteraction()" and it just sounds iOS style. Are you an Objective-C programmer? If so, you should get familiar with the Android widgets and classes and all the utilities that are already implemented and ready to user in your code so you don't have to go through this sort of problems.

Comment: Never worked on iOs. It's a habbit of mine to place any clickListeners, touchListeners, scrollListeners and so on in the same place so that I know where to find them quickly. Although now that you mention it, I should probably change this habbit

Answer (score 0):

you need not to get involved in such coding to get the functionality of a "ViewPager". All the hard work has already been done for you. :)

You just need to implement [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and it will handle everything for you.

Thank you. Happy Coding!